# What are the most efficient ways to take down a Bile Titan?

Tags: helldivers-2

My friends and I recently stepped into Impossible and Helldiver difficulties. When facing the Terminids, this difficulty increase seems to loosely translate to "Spawn more Bile Titans and Chargers".

Now that my friends and I have levelled up quite a bit, we have access to most Stratagems, but we still find ourselves getting overwhelmed by the large number of Bile Titans that seem to come in.

What's the most efficient way to take out one or more Bile Titans? I'm looking for recommendations that both do and don't include offensive stratagem usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've played a bit more and I've come up with some strategies.

As a bit of an intro, Bile Titans as a whole warrant stratagem use. While some support weaponry you already have access to may be effective, it's more efficient to just drop an offensive stratagem or two to take one down than to draw out a Bile Titan's lifespan, during which time you could be overrun by smaller enemies as you try to deal with the Bile Titan itself.

A Bile Titan's weakpoints are the green, fleshy portions of its carapace, typically in the center of its body, as well as its mouth. Attacking it from a distance is the safest way to engage them. The closer a Bile Titan gets to you, the more dangerous they are, and the quicker you're likely to be overwhelmed.

Once those green sections of its body are destroyed, the Bile Titan will not be able to use its "spew bile" ability to hit you from afar. Additionally, dealing a high burst of damage to the Bile Titan's mouth while it is using its spew ability will stagger it, cancelling its spew attack.

As for damage types, with my recommendations, you're going to notice a theme: Explosives. Explosives are the way to deal with armored enemies. That and Railgun-style weaponry which pierces armor like butter.

#### Effective Offensive Stratagems

##### Orbital Railcannon Strike

Unlocked at level 20, the Orbital Railcannon strike will immediately lock onto the nearest and most powerful enemy and hit it *very* hard. Since the Bile Titan is the current most-powerful enemy, it will always be the target. In my experience, a Bile Titan only needs a few more shots to be taken down after being hit by the Railcannon.

The downside of this stratagem is its cooldown and the fact that it's pure single-target. Unless enemies line up very tight, the Railcannon strike will only hit one.

##### Orbital Laser

You only get a few of these per mission, but the Orbital Laser does an incredible amount of damage through its lifetime. It deals constant damage while focused on a target until it dies, then moves on. Against a Bile Titan, it'll take a bit, but it will assuredly kill one if it's the first target of the laser strike. If you have other ways to handle a Bile Titan, I'd recommend them before using an Orbital Laser so as to preserve uses of it for more tricky situations.

##### Eagle 500Kg Bomb

Unlocked at level 15, the 500Kg bomb arrives quite quickly. The bomb's descent can deal damage, and then its resulting powerful explosion can instantly kill a Bile Titan when placed beneath them. If multiple are stacked up, it can kill them all, or at least severely damage them. The explosion originates from the bomb's placement, so if the explosion goes upwards into the green fleshy parts of the Bile Titan, it'll one-shot them.

With a ship upgrade, you can have two 500Kg bombs per Eagle Rearm, which gives you some reusability before it goes on cooldown (or some leeway if you miss).

It's important to note that the 500Kg bomb's explosion radius is deceptively small. I'm hoping that it's buffed, at least a little bit, in the future. The visual explosion is much larger than the damage radius.

##### Eagle 110m Rocket Pods

Like the Orbital Railcannon, the 110m Rocket Pods will target the strongest enemy near its beacon location, which will always be a Bile Titan if it's nearby. It deals hefty damage to its target, and is great at finishing off an already-damaged Bile Titan or softening it up for future attacks. It will not instantly kill a Bile Titan. However, you do get 2 shots per Rearm (3 with an upgrade), and there are only 5 seconds between deployments of Eagle stratagems, so you can theoretically double-up on this stratagem to take one singular Bile Titan down.

---

#### Effective Support Weapons

##### EAT-17 Expendable Anti-Tank

You can purchase this support weapon stratagem very early on. Its call-down time is quick, and its cooldown is a very low ~45 seconds. You get two of them. Pick one up, fire it, pick the other up, fire it. These two are unlikely to kill a Bile Titan on their own unless you're lucky, but they'll severely soften them up.

##### Railgun

The Railgun is great against armored targets. Take it off of safe mode (Hold R and change its settings by right clicking on PC) and you can deal significant damage to armored targets. Just... Don't overcharge it, or you'll die instantly. With a combination of one offensive stratagem I listed before and a couple of Railgun shots to the mouth, a Bile Titan should go down. If you have the time to overcharge it and shoot a Bile Titan a few times in weak areas, the Railgun can very easily dispatch a Bile Titan on its own.

The Railgun doesn't require a backpack slot and is also great against Chargers. I'd recommend this over the Recoilless Rifle in almost all situations, but the Recoilless Rifle is still a fun time to use, especially with a friend to reload for you. More on that below!

##### Recoilless Rifle

Like the Expendable Anti-tank but on steroids. You can reload this yourself or with an ally, but with only one shot per reload and a very painfully-long self-reload animation, you're best off with a friend. Deals significant damage, especially to the Bile Titan's weakpoints. You can reliably kill a Bile Titan with four shots to the mouth/chest with this gun, but the tradeoff is it's not as effective against hordes of smaller enemies (and, again, its painful reload time). If all you're fighting is Bile Titans and Chargers, the Recoilless Rifle is great. If you've got other responsibilities, you may want a different weapon.

##### Spear

The Spear rocket launcher is painful to use. It's got a long reload time (but can be mitigated with a friend, like the Recoilless Rifle), a long lock-on time, requires lock-on to fire, and has a very finnicky lock-on system to boot. None of that feels good. However it does do *considerable* damage to armored enemies. Against a Bile Titan, it can take 3 or 4 shots to kill one, so it's best used as supplementary damage against one than primary damage due to its painful mechanics.

I'm hoping the Spear's lock-on system will be improved in future updates. If it is, this weapon will definitely feel a lot better to use against the targets it's meant to be used on.

---

#### Effective Support Sentries

##### Rocket Sentry

I couldn't leave out this sentry. The Rocket Sentry is great against armored targets... When placed correctly. In my experience, the Terminids love to take out my sentries as quickly as they can, which reduces their effectiveness. When left alone, the Rocket Sentry is excellent. I can't speak to its exact damage output against a Bile Titan, but it quite quickly softens them up.